# Add a path to DLL searching path to help execute EXE that is dependent on a DLL

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I have an EXE file which needs a DLL to be executed correctly, the problem is I need to change location of DLL and it can't be beside the EXE file (e.g. it should be in a \bin folder beside the EXE file). 
How can I add this path (e.g. bin folder) to searching DLL folder of windows?

Comment: Add the dll position to PATH.

Comment: Is it COM or .NET dll ?

Comment: Look at the MSDN page for [DLL Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). From there, you can decide what your options are for placing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add you desired path to the environment variable named PATH

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN page on [DLL Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) describes how the windows loader handles searching for the DLL.
Depending on your situation, you can add the location of your DLL to the `PATH` variable, but do note that this is last in the search list, behind the application folder and all of the system folders.